# Sybase: get a specific string from a binary column

Tags: string, sybase, binary-data

on Sybase, I have a table containing a binary column.
Using `convert(varchar(16384), convert(binary(16384), T1.TEXT)) as Text` I can convert the data contained in to a string format.
Now there is my question: I need to select a string from this field as a new string containing specific words. How can I do it?

Let me take an example. 
If I Suppose in one row the field contains the string "Output of this activity are txt files: the file orange.txt, the file black.txt and eventually the file red.txt", in output of my query I want the field as "orange.txt, black.txt, red.txt".

Is it possible to do it?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this.  This is because neither the BINARY nor the TEXT datatypes under Sybase allow sub-string searching or regular expression processing.

When you are storing character data, VARCHAR or UNIVARCHAR are always the better options.  TEXT as a type should only ever be used if your TEXT fields are larger than your Sybase configured page size.